# Receiving 400 Error Code while calling data using NSRDB API

Tags: python

I followed the instructions to get data using the instructions https://nsrdb.nrel.gov/data-sets/api-instructions.html

While Latitudes and longitudes pertaining to some region provide results, others lead to a 400 error code.

Another challenge, I am facing is downloading data for more than one year at one time (year parameter takes only one input at one time)

Any help with either of the above issues will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Below is code that I am using

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys, os
from IPython.display import display
import io
import requests
import urllib.parse


zipcode = '201301'
address = zipcode
url_zip = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(address) +'?format=json'
response = requests.get(url_zip).json()
lati = response[0]["lat"]
longi = response[0]["lon"]

lat, lon =  lati,longi
api_key = 'api_key_generated'
attributes = 'ghi,dhi,dni,wind_speed,air_temperature,solar_zenith_angle'
year = "2010"
leap_year = 'false'
interval = '60'
utc = 'false'
your_name = 'John+Doe'
reason_for_use = 'beta+testing'
your_affiliation = 'my+institution'
your_email = 'email@gmail.com'
mailing_list = 'false'

url = 'https://developer.nrel.gov/api/solar/nsrdb_psm3_download.csv?wkt=POINT({lon}%20{lat})&names={year}&leap_day={leap}&interval={interval}&utc={utc}&full_name={name}&email={email}&affiliation={affiliation}&mailing_list={mailing_list}&reason={reason}&api_key={api}'.format(year=year, lat=lat, lon=lon, leap=leap_year, interval=interval, utc=utc, name=your_name, email=your_email, mailing_list=mailing_list, affiliation=your_affiliation, reason=reason_for_use, api=api_key)

dataset = requests.get(url=url).content 
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dataset.decode('utf8')),skiprows=2)
```

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with

Comment: Sorry forgot the add the code, added it above

Comment: Steps that I followed: Converted a zipcode/pincode to latitudes and longitudes and then tried to generate the data. During some instances I was able to fetch the data, in other cases I am receiving "EmptyDataError" error, with status":400,"errors":["No data available at the provided location","Data processing failure." while accessing the url

Comment: The error message seems to explain exactly what's going on - i.e., there are no data for that location. You might want to print the latitude and longitude to see if they're sensible

Comment: Using the latitudes and longitudes generated, I am able to extract directly from SAM (System Advisor Model), while the API fetch is failing for some reason. I believe the issue is not with the coordinates but some other element